# Is it guaranteed that a byte-wise zero int is a representation for zero?

Tags: c++

In particular, is the following `assert` guaranteed to hold:

```cpp
int i;
memset(&i, 0, sizeof(int));
assert(i == 0);
```

Answer (score 7):

`int` in C++ can have [ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement), [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), or [signed magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) binary representation per [[basic.fundamental]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.fundamental#7):

> Types `bool`, `char`, `char16_­t`, `char32_­t`, `wchar_­t`, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types. A synonym for integral type is integer type. The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system. [ Example: This International Standard permits two's complement, ones' complement and signed magnitude representations for integral types.  — end example ]

In each of those representations, having all zeros bits has a value of zero for that integer type so you are guaranteed that the assert will always be true.

Comment: And it looks like [C++20 will mandate two's complement signed integers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r0.html) (and C2x probably will too).

Comment: However in one's complement there is a negative zero 111..111 that would not pass the test if i were -0.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yes, but `memset(&i, 0, sizeof(int));` will give you `000..000` which is `0`.

Comment: @NathanOliver you'r right I was already correcting my answer, as the code hold, just "being zero" is a bit weird. I commented as you referred to one's complement too.

Comment: @JoopEggen, I guess another way of phrasing my question is that the zero I'm talking about is the one you get from `int{}`.

Comment: @BeeOnRope `int{}` is zero initialization and the standard says it uses the literal value `0` to initialize with: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#6.1